# Compare two List<POCO> to find differences being case insensitive

Tags: c#, linq

I have two collections:

```
private void ProcessCollectionsData(List<OrganizationUser> databaseUsers, List<OrganizationUser> importedUsers) { ... }
```

There is a property called UserIdentifier (String) and UserId (Int32). This is how I'm comparing them which is producing wrong results and heavy performance bottlenecks:

```
LogMessage(new LogEntry(" - Generating delta for new users...", true));

Task.WaitAll(Task.Run(() =>
{
    newUsers = databaseUsers.Any() ? importedUsers.Where(x => !databaseUsers.Select(y => y.UserIdentifier.ToLower())
                                                      .ToList()
                                                      .Contains(x.UserIdentifier.ToLower()))
                                                  .ToList()
                                   : importedUsers;

    duplicates = newUsers.OrderByDescending(o1 => o1.UserId)
                         .GroupBy(s => s.UserIdentifier, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                         .Where(y => y.Count() > 1);

    foreach (var item in duplicates)
    {
        newUsers.RemoveAll(s => string.Equals(s.UserIdentifier, item.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        newUsers.Add(item.First());
    }
}));

LogMessage(new LogEntry(String.Format(" - Done. New users to be imported: {0}", newUsers.Count)));
```

The data in the `importedUsers` comes from a CSV and can be duplicated and also duplicated with mix case for `UserIdentifier` field. The data in `databaseUsers` is empty first time around. Then, after first run, the import file dumps around a 100,000 users to database and at second and consecutive runs, the `databaseUsers` is loaded with 100,000 existing users and `importedUsers`also brings data in the range of 99,990 to 100,100 (example) which requires me to generate delta collections so that I know which users to mark delete, which to add (new) and remaining (common) needs to be updated.

Can anyone suggest a faster way to do this?

*I can see I'm making a mistake where I'm assigning to the `newUser` collection by using ToLower()*

Correction to above statement, the resulting `newUsers` collection retains case information as desired. So the performance is the real issue here now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the crux of your performance problem is here

```
!databaseUsers.Select(y => y.UserIdentifier.ToLower()).ToList()
```

Given `databaseUsers` can contain 100,000 users you certainly don't want to be pulling that entire list into memory. Getting rid of the `Select` / `ToList` calls should mean you only query the DB which should make a difference

```
importedUsers.Where(x => !databaseUsers.Any(y => 
    y.UserIdentifier.ToLower() == x.UserIdentifier.ToLower()).ToList()
```

Comment: Shifting Select to Contains results in an error as Contains is not a LINQable method here.

Comment: @HassanGulzar `Contains` is supported by EF 4>, if that's not working then you can use `Any`.

Comment: Resharper further suggested this: `importedUsers.Where(x => databaseUsers.All(y => y.UserIdentifier.ToLower() != x.UserIdentifier.ToLower())).ToList()`

Comment: So `!databaseUsers.Any` becomes `databaseUsers.All`

Comment: @HassanGulzar internally `All` is effectively the inverse of `Any` so it doesn't really matter which you use, for me though `Any` is more readable.